# Return an exit code without closing shell

Tags: bash, return, exit, return-code

I'd like to return an exit code from a BASH script that is called within another script, but could also be called directly. It roughly looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dq2-get $1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "ERROR: ..."
  # EXIT HERE
fi
# extract, do some stuff
# ...
```

Now in the line `EXIT HERE` the script should exit and return exit code 1. The problem is that

- I cannot use `return`, because when I forget to source the script instead of calling it, return will *not* exit, and the rest of the script will be executed and mess things up.
- I cannot use `exit`, because this closes the shell.
- I cannot use the nice trick `kill -SIGINT $$`, because this doesn't allow to return an exit code.

Is there any viable alternative that I have overlooked?

Comment: Don't forget to source the script is my advice.

Comment: Software should always be written in a way that misuse cannot lead to problems.

Comment: I disagree with Neils advice. Instead, do not ever source the script but always call it.

Comment: Check the value of `$SHLVL` and conditionally exit or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `x"${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" == x"$0"` to test if the script was sourced or called (false if sourced, true if called) and `return` or `exit` accordingly.

Comment: I tried that, but I got bored, because I couldn't put that into a `function` (because then again I'd miss a way to exit) -- I'd have to place an `if` construction at every place in the script where an error could occur. Or is there a better way?

Comment: You could have the if statement be part of a signal trap and then replace every EXIT HERE with a kill -SIGWHATEVER $$

Comment: The `x`s are 100% unnecessary; they add nothing whatsoever over the behavior of `[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" = "$0" ]`. The only time there's _ever_ a value to the `x$foo` idiom in shells that comply with the POSIX.2 standard (ever since its initial early-90s publication) is when you're using `test` calls with more than three arguments (which the aformentioned standard explicitly flags as obsolescent). And if you need compatibility with ancient shells, `==` is flatly wrong on its face; the only backwards-compatible (or even baseline POSIX-compliant) string comparison operator is `=`.

Comment: Beyond that, this isn't a reliable test; `$0` can be modified by callers using `exec -a name`.

Answer (score 24):

The answer to the question title (not in the body as other answers have addressed) is:

> Return an exit code without closing shell

```
(exit 33)
```

If you need to have `-e` active and still avoid exiting the shell with a non-zero exit code, then do:

```
(exit 33) && true
```

The `true` command is never executed but is used to build a compound command that is not exited by the `-e` shell flag.

That **sets** the exit code without exiting the shell (nor a sourced script).

For the more complex question of exiting (with an specific exit code) either if executed or sourced:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$BASH_SOURCE" == "$0" ] &&
    echo "This file is meant to be sourced, not executed" && 
        exit 30

return 88
```

Will set an exit code of 30 (with an error message) if executed.
And an exit code of 88 if sourced.
Will exit **both** the execution or the sourcing without affecting the calling shell.

Comment: `(exit 33)` Fantastic!!

Comment: This is tremendously useful.  one thing I have had trouble with this though is I like to use 'set -e' to halt a script in its tracks.  unfortunately return 88 will cause this to kill the shell as before.  Are there any pointers on being able to handle that case?

Comment: @openCivilisation The usual solution to keep the shell working even if the `-e` option is set is to make the command line a compound command, the simplest compound command is `(exit 33) && true`. The true command is never actually executed.

Answer (score 12):

Use this instead of exit or return:

```
[ $PS1 ] && return || exit;
```

Works whether sourced or not.

Comment: If use single bracket `[` `]` instead double `[[` `]]`, it will work with `sh` also.

Comment: It did not work for me as written (running as script did not work), but the following works: `[ -v PS1 ] && return || exit`.  A way to test it easily: `[ -v PS1 ] && (echo returning; return) || (echo exiting; exit)`

Comment: Also, if I understand it correctly, this solution does NOT work when source-ing from inside another script. The accepted answer works in that (complex) scenario though.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a function and put the return values in that and then simply either source the script (source processStatus.sh) or call the script (./processStatus.sh) . For example consider the processStatus.sh script that needs to return a value to the stopProcess.sh script but also needs to be called separately from say the command line without using source (only relevant parts included)
Eg:

```sh
check_process ()
{
  if [ $1 -eq "50" ]
  then
    return 1       
  else
    return 0
  fi       
}
```

and

```sh
source processStatus.sh $1
RET_VALUE=$?
if [ $RET_VALUE -ne "0" ]
then
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: `50` doesn't need quotes around it, because it parses to the same two-character string either way. `$1` _does_ need quotes, because it can parse to zero strings, or one string, or more than one string depending on its contents. Consider `check_process "1 -eq 1 -o 39"`; when you don't have the quotes that runs `if [ 1 -eq 1 -o 39 -eq 50 ]`, which is true, whereas `[ "1 -eq 1 -o 39" -eq 50 ]` would correctly be an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return` if you [use `set -e` in the beginning of the script.](https://blog.yossarian.net/2020/01/23/Anybody-can-write-good-bash-with-a-little-effort#fnref:4)

If you just want to check if the function returned no errors, I'd rather suggest rewriting your code like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e # exit program if encountered errors

dq2-get ()
{
  # define the function here
  # ...
  if [ $1 -eq 0 ]
  then
    return 0
  else
    return 255
  # Note that nothing will execute from this point on,
  # because `return` terminates the function.
}

# ...
# lots of code ...
# ...

# Now, the test:
# This won't exit the program.
if $(dq2-get $1); then
  echo "No errors, everything's fine"
else
  echo "ERROR: ..."
fi
# These commands execute anyway, no matter what
# `dq2-get $1` returns (i.e. {0..255}).
# extract, do some stuff
# ...
```

Now, the code above won't leave the program if the function `dq2-get $1` returns errors. But, implementing the function all by itself will exit the program because of the `set -e`. The code below describes this situation:

```sh
# The function below will stop the program and exit
# if it returns anything other than `0`
# since `set -e` means stop if encountered any errors.
$(dq2-get $1)
# These commands execute ONLY if `dq2-get $1` returns `0`
# extract, do some stuff
# ...
```

Comment: `if $(some-function some-arg); then` is a _really_ bad idea, because if `some-function` writes anything to stdout that stdout will be executed as a command and the exit status of the command will be used for the `if` instead of the exit status of `some-function`. Instead, use `if some-function some-arg; then`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question, my case was to `source` a file for some setup, but end the script and skip the setup actions if certain conditions were not met.

I had hit the issue of an attempt to use `exit()` actually causing the closing of my terminal, and found myself here :D

After reviewing the options for the specific solution i just went with something like the below, I also think [Deepaks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27739824/10061651) is worth reviewing if this approach works in your case.

```
if [ -z "$REQUIRED_VAR" ]; then
  echo "please check/set \$REQUIRED_VAR ..."
  echo "skipping logic"
else
  echo "starting logic"
  doStuff()
  echo "completed logic"
fi
```