# Is there a built in linux command that return code matches some integer input parameter?

Tags: linux

Is there a built in linux command that return code matches some integer input parameter? Of course I could write script, but wanted to know if something was built in.

It should work like this:

```
$ ~ cmd 42
$ ~ echo $?
42
```

and the only purpose of `cmd` should be to exit 42.

Comment: There is: `exit $1` or `return $1`

Comment: Max return code is `255`

Comment: Note that it's generally better practice to not rely much on output or exit status, but rather operate directly on a variable, e.g. `printf -v`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return an exit code without closing shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112540/return-an-exit-code-without-closing-shell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could spawn a shell and use exit:

```
$ ~ value=42
$ ~ bash -c "exit ${value}"
$ ~ echo $?
42
```

Note: `awk -v "val=${value}" 'BEGIN{exit val}'` might be a little more lightweight compared to starting a shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a perl one-liner

```
 perl -e 'exit($ARGV[0])' 42
 echo $?
42
```

Comment: He asked for a command built into Linux. Perl is not built into Linux.

Comment: You are very confused.

Comment: @Rob Can you give an example of a command which is built into Linux?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options for this. They essentially all boil down to the same. Call a subprocess that exits with the proper exit code. Any scripting language can be used for this. The most hidden subprocess is

```
$ exitcode=42
$ ( exit $exitcode )
```

otherwise any of the next will do

```
$ exitcode=42
$ awk -v e=$exitcode 'BEGIN{exit e}'
$ perl -e "exit $exitcode"
$ bash -c "exit $exitcode"
$ python -c "exit($exitcode)"
```

and there are many more

Comment: `( exit $exitcode )` is basically the same as `bash -c "exit $exitcode"`. It's shell syntax, not a particular process. Therefore I think that the phrasing is a bit misleading. still +1 for the python example. Never knew that `exit` works without import from `sys`