# Setting up conditional loop in Ansible but receiving undefined error

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have the following tasks

```yaml
- name: detect if table exists
  script: /detect.sh # returns 0 if the "names" table is found
  register: result
  with_sequence: count=100
  when: result.rc != 0

- name: Add new user to detected table
  script: adduser.sh # adds a default user to the table "names"
  when: result.rc == 0
```

Basically what I want to do is to first determine if the table "names" has been created since there may be delays in creating the table hence I am using `with_sequence` to keep trying for a certain number of times.

I am getting an error message

```yaml
The conditional check 'result.rc !=0' failed. The error was: error while evaulating conditional (result.rc !=0); 'result is undefined.
```

I do notice that if I have:

```yaml
- debug: 
    msg: "Return code {{ result.rc }}"
```

before `with_sequence` then I don't get the error and it runs... but I am a bit lost on why.

Thanks!

Comment: Many problems on this single question. It's not a [mre]. You're not debugging the entire `result` (or running with `-vvv` for intermediate loop results). I suspect you should be using some db module (can't tell which without your script...) rather than a script (and if not, you should use `command` or `shell` anyway). You're wrongly looping on a range instead of using [`retry ... until`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met). Your example is not syntactically correct and should fall with an other error...

Comment: Note that `when:` is evaluated for each loop iteration before you execute the task module so the registered variable does not exist until the first run.

Answer (score 0):

One could probably use the following approach shown in a minimal reproducible example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - shell:
      cmd: |
        if (exit $(($RANDOM%2))); then
          echo 'table: created'
        else
          exit 1
        fi
    register: result
    until: result.rc == 0
    retries: 10
    delay: 1

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ (result.stdout | from_yaml).table }}"
    when: result.rc == 0

  - debug:
      var: result
    when: (result.stdout | from_yaml).table == 'created'
```

resulting into a first run of

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] **************************
FAILED - RETRYING: shell (10 retries left).

TASK [shell] ******************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: created
```

or a second run of

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] **************************
FAILED - RETRYING: shell (10 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: shell (9 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: shell (8 retries left).

TASK [shell] ******************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: created
```

which will also help to understand the data structure of [Common Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#common), [Conditions based on registered variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditions-based-on-registered-variables) and [Retrying a task until a condition is met](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met).

**Thanks To**

- [How to generate random number in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/)
- [Return an Exit Code without closing Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53454039/6771046)
- [How to check the Exit Status using an `if` statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55940715/6771046)

**Further Documentation**

- [`from_yaml` filter – Convert YAML string into variable structure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/from_yaml_filter.html)